# Ajax gets only the first object from a list got from the controller

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I just started working with Java for web and I have this basic Quizz project where I integrated ajax.

In spring I have a controller which returns a list of answer objects based on a question id.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view-answers/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public @ResponseBody List<Answer> viewAnswers(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    // TODO: Get all quizzes
    List<Answer> answers = answerService.findByQuestionId(id);

    return answers;
}
```

Using this ajax fuction I retrieve the data from the controller with only one problem: It gets only the first object in full and the rest of the objects are just ID`s of the objects.

```
// DO GET
function ajaxGet(){
    var questionID = $(".questionID").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/view-answers/"+questionID,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(answers){

            $('#answersList .answersUl').empty();
            var ansList = "";
            console.log(answers);
            $.each(answers, function(i, answer){
                var answer = i + "." + answer.answer + "<br />";
                $('#answersList .answersUl ').append(answer);
            });
            console.log("Success: ", answers);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            $("#getResultDiv").html("<strong>Error! Something went wrong.</strong>");
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

It can be a problem with my controller function? The findByQuestionId function is this:

```
@Override
public List<Answer> findByQuestionId(int question_id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Question question = session.find(Question.class, question_id);
    List<Answer> answers = question.getAnswers();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    //Close the session
    session.close();
    return answers;
}
```

This is what I'm getting with ajax right now:

[image]

The important part of my entities:

Quizz:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "quizz_id")
public class Quizz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int quizz_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int nr_participanti;
    private int timp_disp;
    private int nr_intrebari;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quizz", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Question> questions;
```

Question:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String titlu;
    @ManyToOne
    private Quizz quizz;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Answer> answers;
```

Answer:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "answer_id")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int answer_id;
    private String answer;
    private boolean corect;
    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's a problem of lazy loading the related `Answer` objects in your service bean. Since you seem to use Hibernate the list of answers returned by `question.getAnswers()` may not eagerly fetch all answers related to the question. Hibernate loads one-to-many relations lazily by default. You close the Hibernate session at the end of the service method `findByQuestionId` and therefore it is not possible to load the remaining answers as soon as the list is iterated on when generating the response of the controller.

You could try the following in your service:

```
List<Answer> answers = question.getAnswers();
List<Answer> loadedAnswers = answers.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will iterate the list of answers returned for the question relation immediately and add all answers to another transient list. Then it is safe to close the Hibernate session afterwards.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately no result. I added my entities as I feel you might be right and the problem is with my entities but I just can't see the problem here. Also, as I tested right now I see that the problem appears with the POST method too.. I can add answers only to the the first question. To the rest, I get unsupported media type..

Comment: I have adjusted the suggested approach to make sure that the list obtained from the answers relation is really iterated on. The ArrayList constructor only uses the `toArray` method of the source collection which may not work for a Hibernate collection.

Comment: There is not need to use stream and then collect the result, calling question.getAnswers().size() and Hibernate.initialize(question.getAnswers()) are the ways for loading collections

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same problem or somehow finds this question. The problem was indeed in my Entities.
For each entity I had to add two annotations:

@JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.
@JsonBackReference is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Therefore, I annotate ManyToOne objects with @JsonManagedReference and OneToMany lists objects with @JsonBackReference. This was the only part that was missing in order for this to work.